Typescript-Eslint Force Class Members to have type annotation
Is there equivalent of the following rule:
"@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
    "error",
    {
        "variableDeclaration": true
    }
],

for class members?
It produces the following error on missing explicit type annotation:
 const test = new AppComponent();


Expected test to have a type
annotation. (eslint@typescript-eslint/typedef)

We have requirements in our development where it would be really helpful to force class members to have a type, as these are getting missed often in the course of our typescript conversion.

It turns out it always pays to read the documentation! The rule I mentioned actually has an option to specify not just variable but also class member declaration:
memberVariableDeclaration

https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef/#membervariabledeclaration

Typo: mentoined should be mentioned.
